# How to avoid open status bar and bottom buttons bar when app is opened?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app is used for recognize face and it is put on public place in company, so I don't want anyone to close my app or open anything else in the android device.

Is there anyway to avoid using status bar and 3 bottom buttons in flutter when the app is opened or it only can be used when I allow it?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle());
```

This line help you, and how you can use, see example explained below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // Add this line
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle());
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```